# exercise CRUD with Node.js Express et MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, put

> my code :

```
/* ROUTE PUT update */
app.put('/api/products/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  productSchema.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, { ...req.body, _id: req.params.id })
    .then(() => res.status(200).json({ message: 'Modified!' }))
    .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error }));
});
```

> my exercise : PUT: / api / products /: id Will modify the product with
> the supplied _id according to the data sent in the request body. The
> body of the request has the form:

```
{
    "name": string,
    "description": string,
    "price": number,
    "inStock": boolean
}
```

> Will return an object of the form

```
{message: 'Modified!' }
```

> my API error: product found with ID was not updated properly using put
> route !

Answer (score 0):

Remove `_id: req.params.id` from the `update` object, and send only `req.body`. Try this:

```
app.put('/api/products/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  productSchema.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, req.body)
    .then(() => res.status(200).json({ message: 'Modified!' }))
    .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error }));
});
```

Comment: thanks i try this but the message is the same

Comment: it was just a question of placement indeed as I placed my route post first it gave me this message!

Answer (score 0):

Your code will search for a product with the unique params id instead of a. product with the given supplier id. One solution is to have a field supplier_id in the product schema and then use the field in the query as shown below

```
 app.put('/api/products/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  productSchema.updateOne({ supplier_id: req.params.id }, req.body)
    .then(() => res.status(200).json({ message: 'Modified!' }))
    .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error }));
});
```